# How can I dry microfiber cloths, without the dryer or exposing them to dust?

Tags: clothing

To save electricity and protect environment, I eschew drying the microfiber cloths in the dryer. When I place them in an open plastic box to dry, dust, lint and motes end up on the microfiber cloth! I don't use a plastic box with a lid because then water will evaporate much more slowly.

[image]

[How to Clean your Microfiber Towels - Adam's Polishes](https://adamspolishes.com/blogs/news/how-to-clean-your-microfiber-towels-restoration-rejuvenation-and-maintenance)

> Microfiber can be machine dried if you prefer, use a low heat setting and NO FABRIC SOFTENER. Air or line drying is also an option, be sure to do this somewhere the towels cannot be contaminated with dust or lint.

[How to Clean & Care for Microfiber Cloths! - Clean My Space](https://cleanmyspace.com/caring-for-your-microfiber-cloths/)

> ### Can I put microfiber cloths in the dryer?
>
> I recommend tumble drying on low, or no heat. You can even air dry them if you want.

Comment: Related, if you need more options: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/how-to-dry-clothes-without-clothes-line-or-laundry-dryer/20585#20585

Comment: You hang dry them in an environment that is not dusty? Where do you currently dry your clothes? Why is that environment full of dust?

Answer (score 1):

You dry them like all other laundry - you hang them one by one on a clothesline or rack. Drying laundry in a pile is a very bad idea. Microfiber dries quickly, so unless you try this exercise in a particularly dusty environment, no need to worry. Then, *when they are fully dry* put them in a closed box for protected storage.